# How does ConstraintLayout affect on child gravity?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

When I change the gravity of the **ConstraintLayout** child (ex: TextView) to start, the text comes from the left to right perfectly (in LTR Configuration) and when I change the language to Arabic (RTL Configuration) the text comes also from the **Left-to-Right** and it is not the expected behavior (the expected behavior makes the text comes from **Right-to-Left**). 
 When I put the TextView into another container like LinearLayout I get what I want the text comes from **Right-to-eft**.

 
 But still I don't know why when I use the start gravity in any ConstraintLayout child, the result I get is **Left-to-Right** in English and Arabic Configuration also? 
 
And how I can do this by using **ConstraintLayout** ?
This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqVWG.jpg) shows what I get when I set gravity with start, and this [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8R37.jpg) shows what I should get. 
 
 Here is the xml content

```
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/login_logo_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/login_logo_height"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_logo_margin_top"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_login_text_margin_top"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:text="@string/login"

            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/login_login_text_size"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/phone_edit_txt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/login_phone_password_margin_start_end"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/login_phone_password_margin_start_end"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_phone_margin_top"
            android:background="@drawable/simi_round_white_border_transparent_background"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:hint="@string/phone_number"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:padding="@dimen/login_phone_password_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/password_edit_txt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/login_phone_password_margin_start_end"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/login_phone_password_margin_start_end"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_password_margin_top"
            android:background="@drawable/simi_round_white_border_transparent_background"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="@dimen/login_phone_password_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone_edit_txt" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_login_button_margin_top"
            android:background="@drawable/simi_round_green_border_transparent_background"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/login_login_button_padding_right_left"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/login_login_button_padding_right_left"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/login_login_button_text_size"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_edit_txt" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be helpful if you can paste your layout.xml. but two suggestions based on your description:

1. in constraintLayout, replace all **left** to **start**, and **right** to **end**, for example: use `layout_constraintStart_toEndOf` instead of  `app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf`
2. added **android:supportsRtl="true"** in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Why should I put it in Manifest, it works correctly but when using another container